# Clarification on why this C code works

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning C today. I've been coding in managed languages (Java, C#, Python, etc.) for some time now. I thought I was understanding the details of pointers, but then I wrote the following code that worked as expected, but generated an 'incompatible pointer type' warning.

```
void setText(char* output) {
    //code to set output to whatever, no problems here.
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    char output[10];

    setText(&output);

    //[EDITED] ...other test code which printf's and further manipulates output.

    return 0;
}
```

So I googled, and ended up changing the line

```
setText(&output);
```

to

```
setText(output);
```

which got rid of the warning. But now I don't know why the first one was working at all. I was sending the address of an address as far as I can tell (because char* x; is essentially the same as char x[];). What am I misunderstanding and why do both of these work?

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell you why `setText` was working without seeing its implementation.  Although, if all `setText` does is set a variable, after which the program exits, how can you really tell if the program is doing what you want?

Comment: `T *` is *not* the same as `T [K]`. See e.g. http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr

Comment: @Cameron: It isn't for me right now - perhaps you hit a short outage. Could you try again?

Comment: @delnan: That must have been it, works for me too now :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The *type* of `output` is `char [10]`, which decays to a `char *` in the context of a function call (which is why the second variant works).

The type of `&output` is `char (*)[10]`, i.e. a pointer-to-array.  This is not the same thing, hence the compiler warning.  However, the *value* of `&output` (an address) is equivalent to the value of `output` (once it has decayed to a `char *`), so the end result is "as expected".

This may sound like pedantry, but there is a fairly important difference.  Try the following:

```
void foo(const char *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", p);
}

int main(void)
{
    char output[][6] = { "Hello", "world" };

    foo(output[0] + 1);
    foo(&output[0] + 1);
}
```

Recommended reading is [the C FAQ on arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/), in particular question 6.3 and 6.12.

Comment: And it "works" despite the warning because they both end up pointing to the same place.

Comment: Nice example. It really helps illustrate what's actually going on here.

Comment: Yes, that example did help. Thank you.